# Combining 3 GET requests in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 GET requests containing queries in elasticsearch--

```
GET demo5/views/_search/
{
    "_source" : ["user_id"],
    "query": {
       "match": {
          "entity_id" : 1
        }
      }
}



``GET demo5/views/_search/
{
  "_source" : ["entity_id"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "user_id":  1 }},
        { "match": { "user_id": 2 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}



GET demo5/opportunity/_search
{
  "_source" : ["opp_name"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "id":  1 }},
        { "match": { "id": 2 }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want all these 3 requests to be executed at a time so that I can pass the results returned from one query to other ( The types are dependent ) . Btw , the GET requests are different each time.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks !!

Comment: You need to handle that logic in your application code, there is (currently) no way to chain requests in ES.

Comment: Thanks Val ! How do we embed elasticsearch code in application code ? A rough idea would come in handy.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Using NodeJS for my project

Comment: Then you can use the [Javascript client API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html) in order to send your queries.